# jQuery Mobile Load Content Via Ajax Before Page Shown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, cordova

I am very experienced with jquery, but jquery mobile is very new to me. I am developing an app using cordova and jquery mobile.

So i have a multi page setup in the html, with navigation bars that switch the pages. All works great there, however, i need to load the page content via ajax when the page is changed.

I am managing to do this with a post request to an external web server that generates the content, then caches it inside a local database via the app. I am currently doing this with the "pagebeforeshow" event.

The problem is, when the user clicks the menu item, jquery mobile has already switched the page before the ajax call in "pagebeforeshow" is fired, which means we see a blank page delay while the content is requested.

So my question is: Is there a way to either prevent jquery mobile from switching the page automatically on menu click so that i can catch the event, grab the content and then manually display the page with changePage() or is there an event i can hook into that fires well before the transition takes place?

So the idea is they click the menu item, a full screen loader shows (which works) , load the content and then display the page, not display the page then load the content....

Make sense?

Comment: did you read the [jQuery Mobile “Page” Events – What, Why, Where, When & How?](https://jqmtricks.wordpress.com/2014/03/26/jquery-mobile-page-events/) and [pagecontainerbeforechange – How to use it](https://jqmtricks.wordpress.com/2014/07/13/pagecontainerbeforechange/) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I'd go about it would be to not use `pagebeforeshow` and instead have the page initally covered by a splash screen.

Then when the splash screen is loaded and displayed (image onLoad or similar) start the AJAX call, which once finished, fades out the splash screen and shows the actual content.

Comment: i actually did go down this route in the end, thanks for your answer.